# Подскажите пожалуйста, почему возникает данная ошибка java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method test(unt.Qwa)

Tags: java, selenium

Всем привет! Есть простой код:

```
package unt;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Qwa {

    @Test

    public void Login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
    }
}
```

При компиляции возникает ошибка:
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method test(unt.Qwa) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@282ba1e

```
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Process finished with exit code -1
Спасибо.

Comment: А где сами тесты в методе. Ваш метот только что-то создает но не тестирует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где сами тесты в методе? Ваш метод только создает что-то, но не тестирует.

Я думаю что должны быть какие-то тесты внутри метода.

```
public class AppTest 
{
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        assertTrue( true ); // чтобы прошёл
        assertTrue( false ); // чтобы упал
    }
}
```

или применительно к Вашему

```
public class Qwa {

    @Test

    public void Login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        assertTrue( driver != null );
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
    }
}
```

без этого это не тест, а какой-то вызов чего то там

Comment: Большое спасибо!